# Compiling without including a header file

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors

In a particular C project, a file say file1.c uses a function say FUNCTION2(). The FUNCTION2() is declared in  file2.c. An extern declaration of FUNCTION2() is there in file1.h

The file1.c adds only file1.h.
In file1.h, the file2.c/file2.h is not added. Still the compilation is successful and the functionality is working.

In the compilation list of the project, file2.c/file2.h is compiled first. But is that possible to call functions without adding the header file?

Comment: Standard practice would be to put the forward extern declare of FUNCTION2 in file2.h and then `#include "file2.h"` in all source files calling FUNCTION2  Or if you don't want to use the header files, put a local declaration of the external function at the top of the source file. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: from another angle: think what happens if you one day change the function in file2 e.g. other return value, then you need to go through all .c files that use that function instead of just updating the header file2.h, the compiler will then tell where to fix instead of getting an unresolved error from the linker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but I wouldn't advise it. You have arranged things to force the compiler to exploit *implicit declaration*:

```
int main()
{
    foo(2); /* The compiler emits this by implicit declaration. */       
    return 0;
}

int foo(int x)
{
    return x;
}
```

In your explicit case, `extern` is telling the compiler to expect `foo` to come from a different compilation unit.

The standard thing to do would be to put a prototype of `foo` in a header and include that.